# Using ssh key for SFTPHook - correct formatting for ssh_conn_id

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, airflow, connection-string, airflow-2.x

I've created 5 test connections in my external-connections.env file while testing Airflow locally and none of these work. I'm able to connect to the ftp via FileZilla w. the private ssh key file, host, username but can't seem to get the connection format correct.

```
from airflow.providers.sftp.hooks.sftp import SFTPHook 
from airflow.models import BaseOperator   

class TestCustomOperator(BaseOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        ftp_hook = SFTPHook(ssh_conn_id='sftp....')
```

The first 3 I tried just using the 'private_key' directly in the connection and see the error (I ran `sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/" -e "s/\S\{64\}/&\n/g" | sed "s/^\s//g" ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to get the formatting for the 2nd conn):

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py",
> line 444, in _pkey_from_private_key
> raise AirflowException('Key must have BEGIN and END header/footer on separate lines.')

The AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_TEST_DEFAULT is a json file that looks like this:

```
{
"private_key" : "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRI.... ----"
}
```

For the last 2 connections I keep seeing the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} ' TypeError: Object of type SFTPHook is not JSON serializable

See below for the connection formats I've tried:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_DEFAULT=ssh://username@host?private_key=-----BEGIN+OPENSSH+PRIVATE+KEY-----\nb3BlbnNzaiSthkRzFvly\nNRZkj8vtwqTy6h\nP0KSM3VlhrND\nCuaSUQERFU0tUT1AtRjlMRUtETgE=\n-----END+OPENSSH+PRIVATE+KEY-----

AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_TWO_DEFAULT=ssh://username@host?private_key=-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\nb3BlbnNzaiSthkRzFvly\nNRZkEj8vtwqTy6h\nP0KSM3hrND\nCuaSUXeMU0tUT1AtRjlMRUtETgE=\n-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n

AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_THREE_DEFAULT=ssh://username@host?private_key=-----BEGIN+OPENSSH+PRIVATE+KEY-----\nb3BlbnNzaiSthkRzFvly\nNRZk8vtwqTy6h\nP0KSlhrND\nCuaQERFU0tUT1AtRjlMRUtETgE=\n-----END+OPENSSH+PRIVATE+KEY-----\n

AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_TEST_DEFAULT=ssh://username@host?conn_timeout=10&key_file=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fairflow%2Frepo%2Fairflow_output%2Fid_rsa.json

AIRFLOW_CONN_SFTP_TEST_TWO_DEFAULT=ssh://username@host?conn_timeout=10&key_file=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fairflow%2Frepo%2Fairflow_output%2Fid_rsa.txt
```